# Newtonian/Relativistic Solutions of Fluid Disks in orbit around a massive body

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, magnetohydrodynamics, accretion-disk

I have been trying to make an RMHD (Relativistic Magneto-Hydro Dynamics) Set-up of a Disk around a Massive Rotational Body.

The initial paper I have been studing a paper which uses a Fishbone & Moncrief (1976) (FM76)[RELATIVISTIC FLUID DISKS IN ORBIT AROUND KERR BLACK HOLES] torus in hydrostatic equilibrium around a rapidly spinning Kerr black hole.

Is there a Newtonian-NonGR (Non GENERAL relativistic) solution, ignoring the Self-Gravity, for a problem like this? (I mean, adding a $
\propto \dfrac{1}{r}$  Gravitational Potential.)

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: There is section IV. NEWTONIAN MODELS  in the article RELATIVISTIC FLUID DISKS IN ORBIT AROUND KERR BLACK HOLES by Leslie G. Fishbone and Vincent Moncrief - see on http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1976ApJ...207..962F&amp;data_type=PDF_HIGH&amp;whole_paper=YES&amp;type=PRINTER&amp;filetype=.pdf